# Rails/RSpec - writing tests for original helper methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, helper

I'm on the chapter 5 exercises for [Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec-layout_exercises) and am trying to wrap my head around how Rails/Rspec is testing a helper method `full_title` in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`. All of my tests are in `spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb` and within them, I'm calling `full_title` to cut down on code bloat.

So, in order to test the original `full_title` I create a test in `spec/helpers/application_helpers_spec.rb` and include it via `spec/support/utilities.rb`. The code is passing, but I want to understand the process (order to operations) to what is going on. Thank you.

Can I think of it like this?

1. Rspec begins to run `static_pages_spec.rb` (including `utilities.rb`)
2. Rspec sees the full_title method in `static_pages_spec.rb`
3. Rspec begins to run `application_helper_spec.rb`
4. Rspec sees `describe "full_title" do` in `application_helper_spec.rb`
5. Rspec looks up original `full_title` method and finishes test for `application_helper_spec.rb`
6. Rspec finishes tests in static_pages_spec.rb`, iterating through above process when`full_title` is called.

**static_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  subject { page }

  shared_examples_for "all static pages" do
    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: heading) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title(page_title)) }
  end

  describe "Home page" do
    before { visit root_path }
    let(:heading)    { 'Sample App' }
    let(:page_title) { '' }

    it_should_behave_like "all static pages"
    it { should_not have_selector 'title', text: '| Home' }
  end

  describe "Help page" do
    before { visit help_path }
    let(:heading) { 'Help' }
    let(:page_title) { 'Help' }

    it_should_behave_like "all static pages"
  end

  describe "About page" do
    before { visit about_path }
    let(:heading) { 'About' }
    let(:page_title) { 'About Us' }

    it_should_behave_like "all static pages"
  end

  describe "Contact page" do
    before { visit contact_path }
    let(:heading) { 'Contact' }
    let(:page_title) { 'Contact' }

    it_should_behave_like "all static pages"   
  end

  it "should have the right links on the layout" do
    visit root_path
    click_link "About"
    page.should have_selector 'title', text: full_title('About Us')
    click_link "Help"
    page.should have_selector 'title', text: full_title('Help')
    click_link "Contact"
    page.should have_selector 'title', text: full_title('Contact')
    click_link "Home"
    page.should have_selector 'title', text: full_title('')
    click_link "Sign up now!"
    page.should have_selector 'title', text: full_title('Sign up')
    click_link "sample app"
    page.should_not have_selector 'title', text: full_title('| Home')
  end
end
```

**application_helper_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApplicationHelper do

  describe "full_title" do
    it "should include the page title" do
      full_title("foo").should =~ /foo/
    end

    it "should include the base title" do
      full_title("foo").should =~ /^Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App/
    end

    it "should not include a bar for the home page" do
      full_title("").should_not =~ /\|/
    end
  end
end
```

**application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper

    #Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
    def full_title(page_title)
        base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
        if page_title.empty?
            base_title
        else
            "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it this way:

The **'full_title'** called in `static_pages_spec.rb` (including utilities.rb) is running the **'full_title'** method described in application_helper.rb.

The `application_helper_spec.rb` is validating the string/value (page_title) passed through full_title. 
If I'm not mistaken, it does this each time the `full_title` method is called in your tests.

Comment: Here's what I'm confused about. Without either a test or the actual full_title method in application_helper_spec.rb, my test in static_pages_spec.rb will fail with a 'no full_title method error'. I understand putting the actual full_title method in application_helper_spec.rb will ensure the test passes, but why does putting a test for the original full_title method in application_helper_spec.rb also ensure the test passes?

Comment: Alrighty so when you describe ApplicationHelper in application_helper_spec.rb, it's calling that module.  The tests below ensure that what's being passed through is valid/the data that you want.

So the key part of this in answering your question is the 
'describe ApplicationHelper' line in application_helper_spec.rb.  With this, the tests 'understand' the full_title method and allows you to use it in your tests.

Comment: No prob, I just got through the book myself.  A lot of magic going on in Rails.

Comment: Awesome. Any gotchas in the coming chapters I should watch out for?

Comment: Make sure to do the exercises, I ran into gravatar isssues quite a few times that drove me INSANE.  Literally spent hours trying to figure out wtf was going on.